# react-native initial lifecycle hooks not being called

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With the code below, I'm unable to get a reference to the `Text` component inside of `TestText` until AFTER triggering an additional re-render. Am I crazy? Or is this a bug in react-native?

"`constructor`", "`componentWillMount`", and "`render`" are called immediately upon launching the application, as expected. However, "`ref`", and "`componentDidMount`" are not called until manually triggering a re-render via `this.setState()` after the 5 second delay.

Platform: Android

React-Native Version: 0.42.3

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class TestText extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        console.warn('constructor');
        this.textRef = null;
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.warn('willMount');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.warn('didMount');
    }

    render() {
        console.warn('render');
        return (
            <View>
                <Text
                    ref={(me) => {
                        console.warn('ref: ' + (me ? 'not null' : 'null'));
                        this.textRef = me;
                    }}>
                    {'TEST'}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

}

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = {
        test: 0
      };
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            test: 1
        });
      }, 5000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TestText />
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: Saw your question [over here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13182), 'm having the same problem (except in web React not React Native).